# pysnmp mib2dev.py failing

Tags: python, python-2.7, snmp, pysnmp

Good day,

I am trying to generate a simulator for snmpsim using the `mib2dev.py` tool in pysnmp. I keep getting a `ValueError: Empty module name` and am not sure why. I have ensured that I have the latest pysnmp, pycrypt, and snmpsim. I am running on mac.

The needed packages were installed with easy_install. I am using brew's python 2.7.8. I have removed all packages and python then reinstalled them. That was not helpful.

I did review this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429161/pysnmp-exceptions), but they are getting a different error.

This MIB is taken from [here](http://www.nealc.com/blog/blog/2013/02/23/writing-an-snmp-agent-with-a-custom-mib-using-pysnmp/). I can't show my actual mib but it is producing the same error as this small mib.

I have no issue coding an agent out. At this time I can only find examples of either scalar only or table only agents. If you know of some good resources with examples for building an agent with pysnmp, that would be awesome.

MIB:

```
MY-MIB DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN

IMPORTS
        OBJECT-TYPE, Integer32, NOTIFICATION-TYPE, enterprises
                     FROM SNMPv2-SMI
;

myCompany       OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= {enterprises 42}

testCount OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX Integer32
    MAX-ACCESS read-only
    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION "A sample count of something."
    ::= {myCompany 1}

testDescription OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX OCTET STRING
    MAX-ACCESS read-only
    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION "A description of something"
    ::= {myCompany 2}

testTrap NOTIFICATION-TYPE
    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION "Test notification"
    ::= {myCompany 3}

END
```

.py script from build-pysnmp-mib:

```
$ mib2dev.py --pysnmp-mib-dir="." --mib-module=MY-MIB.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/mib2dev.py", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('snmpsim==0.2.4', 'mib2dev.py')
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 696, in run_script

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1614, in run_script

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/snmpsim-0.2.4-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/mib2dev.py", line 240, in <module>
    [ builder.ZipMibSource(m).init() for m in mibDirs ]
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pysnmp-4.2.5-py2.7.egg/pysnmp/smi/builder.py", line 45, in init

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pysnmp-4.2.5-py2.7.egg/pysnmp/smi/builder.py", line 103, in _init

ValueError: Empty module name
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: As smilint and pysnmp suggest, you need to add MODILE-IDENTITY clause to your original MIB  file like this:

```
IMPORTS
    MODULE-IDENTITY, OBJECT-TYPE, Integer32, NOTIFICATION-TYPE, enterprises
                 FROM SNMPv2-SMI
;

my-MIB MODULE-IDENTITY
   LAST-UPDATED "201501120000Z"
   ORGANIZATION  "X"
   CONTACT-INFO  "X"
   DESCRIPTION   "X"
   REVISION      "201501120000Z"
   DESCRIPTION   "X"
   ::= { enterprises 42 }

myCompany       OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { my-MIB 123 }
...
```

In general, to troubleshoot such issues I'd run smilint to see if the original MIB is good and libsmi setup is working alright. Next try to run:

```
smidump -f python MY-MIB.txt
```

to see what is the result of smidump invocation which is fed to libsmi2pysnmp (also invoked by build-pysnmp-mib).

When everything works, build-pysnmp-mib invokes smidump which produces Python code and passes it to libsmi2pysnmp script. The latter generates pysnmp-compliant code (e.g. MY-MIB.py).

It looks to me that smidump step is the most fragile: it easily fails on unavailable MIBs mentioned in IMPORT statements or syntax errors/incompatibilities in MIBs.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The size of MY-MIB.py is 1834 according to `ls -l MY-MIB.py`

I tried the smidump by it self and got the following:

 `$ smidump -f python ./MY-MIB`
 `./MY-MIB:29: missing MODULE-IDENTITY clause in SMIv2 MIB`
 `smidump: module `./MY-MIB' contains errors, expect flawed output`
 `smidump: aborting due to severe parsing errors`
 `smidump: use the -k option to force continuation`